# Multiple Spring Batch jobs executing concurrently causing deadlocks in the Spring Batch metadata tables

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

We have multiple Spring Batch jobs each running in their own java instance using the CommandLineJobRunner. All of the jobs are started simultaneously, only read/write flat files and update the same Spring Batch metadata hosted in SQL Server. The only database involved is the Spring Batch metadata database.

When the multiple jobs are started simultaneously we get SQL deadlock exceptions. A more detailed stack trace can be found below. From the database perspective we can see that the deadlock victims were doing one of the following: Insert into BATCH_JOB_SEQ default values or Delete from BATCH_JOB_SEQ  where ID < some_number.

We are utilizing a default MapJobRegistry, and either the default job repository or specifying the JobRepositoryFactoryBean. For the data source used to interact with the Spring Batch database we have tried both the DriverManagerDataSource or a DBCP2 pooling BasicDataSource both using the standard Microsoft SQL Server SQLServerDriver. I can upload more specific config files but in my testing as long as I use the SQL Server and standard Spring configuration the issues occur.

In my investigation I think the issue is due to how the default incrementer class, org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.SqlServerMaxValueIncrementer, increments the job and step instance ids in conjunction with how the SQL Server database tables are constructed. The code in SqlServerMaxValueIncrementer is synchronized so if we were running all the jobs in the same Java instance this would not be an issue.

If we implement the Spring Batch metadata in a DB2 database we do not have a problem. The SQL Server implementation uses actual tables and the DB2 implementation uses sequence objects.

Has anyone run into this issue? Am I just missing something? It seems like whenever we have a problem like this it is as simple as go set setting xxx in yyy. If not, does anyone know why Spring Batch doesn’t implement sequence objects in the SQL Server implementation?

Stack trace:

```
[org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner] - <Job Terminated in error: Could not increment identity; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Transaction (Process ID 74) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.>
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Could not increment identity; 
nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: 
Transaction (Process ID 74) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.SqlServerMaxValueIncrementer.getNextKey(SqlServerMaxValueIncrementer.java:124)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.AbstractDataFieldMaxValueIncrementer.nextLongValue(AbstractDataFieldMaxValueIncrementer.java:1
28)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobInstanceDao.createJobInstance(JdbcJobInstanceDao.java:108)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:135)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Configuration:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager"
    lazy-init="true">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="batchPoolingDataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="jobRegistry"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry" />

<bean id="jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor">
    <property name="jobRegistry" ref="jobRegistry" />
</bean>

<bean id="jobRepository"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="databaseType" value="SQLSERVER" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="batchPoolingDataSource" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="jobLauncher"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
</bean>

<bean id="jobExplorer"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.JobExplorerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="batchPoolingDataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="jobOperator"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobOperator">
    <property name="jobExplorer" ref="jobExplorer" />
    <property name="jobLauncher" ref="jobLauncher" />
    <property name="jobRegistry" ref="jobRegistry" />
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope">
    <property name="proxyTargetClass" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="batchPoolingDataSource"  class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://server info" />
    <property name="username" value="${batch.jdbc.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${batch.jdbc.password}" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxTotal" value="15" />
    <property name="maxWaitMillis" value="5000" />
</bean>

<bean id="batchDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://server info" />
    <property name="username" value="${batch.jdbc.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${batch.jdbc.password}" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Can you provide your transaction configuration settings (as well as any SqlServer configuration)?  With regards to why Spring Batch doesn't use sequences for SqlServer, it's because historically they haven't been there (sequences were a new feature in SqlServer 2012).

Comment: Added configuration information

Comment: Any additional information on resolving this? I'm facing the same problem and have resorted to using a RetryTemplate with a ExponentialRandomBackOffPolicy to try and recover from this. It works, but  poorly.

Comment: We ended up switching to a DB2 database.

Comment: Adding to my comment..got sidetracked. We ended up switching to a DB2 database which is why I didn't mark it as answered more like abandoned. The underlying problem is in the way that SQL server is handling the keys.  The DB2 schema defines the tables in question as (BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_SEQ, BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_SEQ, BATCH_JOB_SEQ) as sequence tables where the SQLServer ddl just defines those as regular tables with one column. SQLServer does have the sequence option and I am guessing they have just never bothered to update it.

Answer (score 15):

After researching this further, and partially heading down the path of working on versions of the DAOs that back the `JobRepository` and work with SQL Server `IDENTITY` instead of sequences, I stumbled upon the way to address this without much more than a bit of configuration.

The simple way to address this is to configure the `databaseType` and `isolationLevelForCreate` properties of the `JobRepository`. Here are the settings I am using with SQL Server 2008:

```
<bean id="jobRepository"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="databaseType" value="SQLSERVER" />
    <property name="isolationLevelForCreate" value="ISOLATION_REPEATABLE_READ" />
</bean>
```

I've tested this with 30 jobs (same job with different parameters) being launched by a group of Quartz jobs and thus far I haven't seen any issues.

I've also kept retry code (see comment on question) in place when launching the jobs just to catch any possible deadlocks and allow it to retry. It may be a moot point but I can't risk having jobs fail to launch.

I think that mentioning these settings in the Spring Batch documentation regarding launching multiple jobs at a given time when using SQL Server as your dataSource would be quite helpful to others. Then again, I guess not many people are stuck with SQL Server.